# Plotting a stereographic projection

Tags: complex-analysis, planar-graphs, stereographic-projections

I need to sketch the image under the stereographical projection of sphere where the spherical cap $A < X < 1,$ with center lying on the equator, for fixed $ A. $ Separating the cases according to various ranges of $A.$

Here $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 1$ and $ (X,Y,Z) $ are points the unit sphere.

Comment: What have you done ? Do you see that it will be a disk orthogonal to the equator in all cases ?

Comment: I have suppressed the tag "planar-graph" that had nothing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphical answer. The stereographic projection is from the North Pole (materialized by a star) onto the equatorial plane. Please note that all the blue disks (images of spherical caps whose limits are in red) have their centers on the $x$ axis,  are orthogonal to the equator circle but are not concentrical. Waiting for your comments.

For the computations, see the reference I have given about an identical question.

[image]

Comment: No comment, a day after...